# Develop intuition for conditional probability composition

Tags: probability

I have heard many sources state that this is inherently non-intuitive, however maybe somebody here has broken the code and can help.

Scenario described based on [video](https://youtu.be/uL31gpFdarc). In the scenario we have two guys:

- Frank works on flights. He goes outside every 5 minutes. Records if there's an airplane in the visible sky. **5%** of the time there is, **95%** there isn't any. A plane in the sky is event **A**.
- Ralph works on radars. His job is to go out every time the radar says there's a plane and check if radar is correct. He determines the radar to be rather accurate 99% accuracy. Radar notifying a positive is event **B**.

The non-intuitive part is this $P(A|B)$. The result is only **34%**.

I interpret that as Ralph gives Frank a call that the radar says there is a plane in the sky. Frank goes out and gets a result dramatically different from what Ralph experiences.

What can one attribute that dramatic difference to? Is it incorrect to interpret that Frank only goes out when Ralph calls him?

Please consider perfect conditions: plane out of the sky in less than 5 minutes, Frank and Ralph rather close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a world in which radar had been invented but planes hadn't. Now imagine that Ralph were somehow transported to that world and looked for planes on the radar. Even though the radar is 99% accurate, once in a while it'll look like there's a plane on the radar. Should Ralph believe that there's a plane outside? No! In that world, $P(A) = 0$ since planes haven't been invented!

The same phenomenon is happening in your question. The probability of a plane isn't 0, but it's low — only 5%. That is, based on your first bullet point, only 5% of the time is there a plane flying overhead. That means that when Ralph sees $B$, it's more likely than not to be a "false positive" — the radar says there's a plane even though there isn't. On the other hand, in our world when we know that there sometimes are planes overhead, and the radar is (imperfectly) informative about whether there's a plane. So when Ralph sees $B$, he should think it's more likely that there is a plane than if he hadn't seen $B$. But because Ralph has *prior information* that planes are rare, Ralph shouldn't think the probability there is a plane is 99% — he should discount it to some extent. Exactly how much is given by [Bayes' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Also, based on the information in your question, the correct answer is not 34%. If $P(B | A) = .99$ and $P(B | \text{not}\,A) = .01$, we should have $P(A |B) \approx .84 = 84\%$.